# CSS addClass doesn't change background-image

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, addclass

I want to apply image "bars_small.png" (which is the white image that you see on hover) when I make this button active.

The jQuery:

```
        $("#btn_bars").click(function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass('btn_header_active')){
                    $('.ch-grid .btn_header_active').removeClass('.btn_header_active');
                    $(this).addClass('btn_header_active');
                });
            }
        });
```

CSS:

```
#btn_bars .btn_header_active .ch-info{

    background-image: url(http://www.zwoop.be/develop/images/fisheye/bars_small.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

I refer to this jsFiddle for the complete menu code and the visual effect: 
http://jsfiddle.net/kimgysen/6ryav/

Comment: Where is `.ch-grid .btn_header_active`?

Comment: I updated; I removed the addClass method from the callback function. What I would like to achieve is that the 'btn_header_active' class is erased from all menu items first, and then re-applied to the currently active menu button.

Comment: in your fiddle you are trying to add the `btn_header_active` class back to the item you have just taken it off, also your css selector for the active is wrong, it should be `#btn_bars.btn_header_active .ch-info` [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/6ryav/6/)

Comment: Yes, that's what I try to do. I first want to take off the active class from each item, and then re-apply it on the item that has been clicked. I tried your fiddle, the menu item doesn't seem to stay active?

Comment: Perfect, thanks Pete. If you put the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your click function to the following:

```
$(".ch-item").click(function(){
    var thisButton = $(this);
    if(!thisButton.hasClass('btn_header_active')){
        $('.ch-grid .btn_header_active').removeClass('btn_header_active');
        thisButton.addClass('btn_header_active');
        active_header = 1;
    }
});
```

and then change your css selector from `#btn_bars .btn_header_active .ch-info` to `#btn_bars.btn_header_active .ch-info` (no space between the id and first class as the class is on the element with the id, not a sub element of it) it should work as you want:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/6ryav/15/)

Comment: Many thanks, as a matter of fact, this is the first time I heared about this difference. I checked out this helpful article: http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/